# increasing the time of search-forward using sumatra-forward.el

Tags: latex, auctex, pdf

[sumatra-forward.el](http://william.famille-blum.org/software/sumatra/sumatra-forward.el) 
allows to do a [forward-search](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/I_002fO-Correlation.html) from a place in a tex file to the corresponding place in its compiled pdf file viewed by [SumatraPDF](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org). The command to do the job is `M-x sumatra-jump-to-line`. After invoking this command, the corresponding place in pdf file takes the red color for few millisecond. Is it possible to increase this really brief time?

Comment: I doubt that's a thing that has much to do with Emacs and is most probably configurable or hard-coded in SumatraPDF.

Comment: Although the question ends up being about `sumatra` and not `Emacs`, leaving open because the issue stems from `sumatra-forward.el` which is part of Emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question isn't actually about Emacs—hence my close vote.

You need to configure SumatraPDF accordingly.  On a cursory look at the [documentation](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/settings.html#InverseSearchCmdLine) I didn't find any option to increase the highlighting time, but you can make it permanent until the next mouse click by changing the `HighlightPermament` setting in the `ForwardSearch` group to `true`.